# VS Code: How to disable Security Warning for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to use VS Code a bit more lately as a replacement for Notepad++ but there is one feature in VS Code that is super annoying. I'll be typing away on a PowerShell .ps1 file (either locally on my work machine or on a file from another server via UNC path) and a Security Warning will pop-up at the top:

[image: VS Code Security Warning]

And after a few seconds a PowerShell Output pops open at the bottom:

[image: PowerShell Output window]

I'm not sure why these windows keep popping open. I'm assuming my PowerShell script is running in the background or something, but how do I disable these windows? This is the main reason why I switch back to Notepad++ or use Atom.

BTW: I do not want my PowerShell scripts to run within VS Code while I'm coding.

Comment: AFAIK the scripts are not actually running in the background, but the code is being accessed in order to provide syntax highlighting.  you should be able to fix the problem by running `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Unrestricted` from an elevated prompt.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I wasn't really sure what was going on in the background, but now I know. I'll try your suggestion of Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted and see how that works out. Cheers! -Keith

Comment: if not let me know, its been a while since I used VS Code but that's a best guess.  also if your on windows give the ISE a shot, not as extensible but it's got some useful features that are not yet available in code(at least they weren't last time I checked)

Comment: Dang it. It seemed to have worked for a few minutes but the same thing is happening again. Ugh!  BTW: I like using the PowerShell ISE for quick in-place testing, but that's about it. I prefer using a full featured code editor for my PS scripting. VS Code has gotten better but still not exactly where I want it to be. If I can turn off this current pesky problem then VS Code would be almost ideal.

Comment: Have you checked out [This Issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/325) from the GitHub?  maybe try removing all modules and see if it clears the issue?  then add them back until you find the problem one?  And I'll have to go back and give code a better look, generally use ISE since getting anything installed on my work PC is a pain but if it's improved I may just jump through the hoops.

Comment: Ahh...thanks. That might be the problem. I do use a third party module for better logging, but I would hate to delete that module if that is what is causing my problem in VS Code. I'd rather keep the module and use some other code editor. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129650/discussion-between-mike-garuccio-and-keith).

Comment: Remember that `Unrestricted` execution policy should only be used for debugging, and never in a production environment.